# Using .apply in python to apply a mapper

Tags: python, pandas

this should be very simple but I can't figure it out.

I have a 'mapper' DataFrame that looks something like this:

```
mapper={'old_values':[105,312,269],'new_values':[849,383,628]}
df=pd.DataFrame(mapper)
```

I then have another dataframe with a column that contains old values. I simply want to convert them all to their new values (e.g. all 105's should become 849's). I think I need to use df.apply but I can't find an example of how to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to choose [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) method which performs similar to a python dictionary in functionality to aid in the mapping of values from one series to another than go for a slow `apply` function here.

```
df['old_values'].map(df.set_index('old_values')['new_values'])
Out[12]:
0    849
1    383
2    628
Name: old_values, dtype: int64
```

The only modification you need to make here is:

```
new_df['old_values'].map(old_df.set_index('old_values')['new_values'])
```

But do note that this introduces `NaN` for keys not found in the original `DF`.(Any unseen value encountered by the new `DF` would be coerced to `NaN`).

If this is the behavior you'd expect then `map` is an ideal method.

---

Although, if your intention is to simply replace the values and leave the missing keys as they were before, you can opt for [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) method.

```
new_df['old_values'].replace(old_df.set_index('old_values')['new_values'])
```

Comment: Thanks, the first option worked. It also looks like it didn't replace missing keys with NaN (it just kept them the same)

Comment: Good to know that. Which means that your old `DF` was a super set of the new one. If this answer worked, then you could mark it as the chosen one.